# How to mock a class attribute on instantiation

Tags: python, mocking

I have an object (say `Class A`) that's instantiating another Class that connects to a remote db, which I don't have access to.

I want to use `method1` in `Class A`, which only needs `attr1` of the class to function.  How can I mock `attr2` upon instantiating `Class A` so I can use `ClassA.method1` without getting an error?

```
from module_a import SomeDbHandler

    Class A:
        def __init__(self, attr1):
            self.attr1= attr1
            self.attr2= SomeDbHandler()

        def method1(self):
            # needs self.attr1 but does not need self.attr2

    # some kind of mock or patch?
    a=A('attr')
    a.method1()
```

Note:

I understand the best thing is to decouple `SomeDbHandler` and `Class A`, although I don't have control over the implementation of `Class A`. So I think the best option for me is to mock `self.attr2= SomeDbHandler()`.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How is SomeDbHandler defined within the module Class A is in? Is it imported?

Comment: Mocking part of the class you're trying to test is a bit of a code smell. Can't you mock `SomeDbHandler` instead? Even better, inject the handler into the constructor rather than instantiating it there, reduce the coupling.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the suggestion.  Agree, I would decouple the two classes, although I don't have control over the implementation of `Class A`, I can only use it as it is.  How would I mock `SomeDbHandler ` in this case?

Comment: `mock.patch("path/to/module", "SomeDbHandler")`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks Daniel.  The original implementation is a bit complicated.  The `SomeDbHandler` is instantiating another class inside in the same module. If suppose `SomeDbHandler`  is imported, how would I mock it?

Comment: create `class B(A)` and initialize only the attributes you need

Comment: @panda-34 Thanks! I have not thought of that.  This is definitely better than mocking.